# How can I get Visual Studio Web Development Server (Cassini) to send the domain name of the request to the web application?

Tags: visual-studio, webrequest, cassini, domain-name

We're developing an application that is sensitive to the domain name of the request. The problem we're running into is that we have to use IIS in order to test the application because Cassini will only send "localhost" as the requested domain despite using a different domain in the address bar. While IIS does give us better performance than Cassini, we would still like to be able to hit F5 to run our application from within Visual Studio.

Is there any configuration that can be done to specify the domain name to use in Cassini?

Comment: This is why I advocate developing in IIS instead of Cassini. No nasty surprises when you deploy. You can hit F5 to run an application in IIS from Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

I just released the CassiniDev 3.5.1/4.0.1 beta with a simple test fixture example if you are interested.

It supports arbitrary IP addresses and host names. Should fit your needs quite nicely.

http://cassinidev.codeplex.com

Comment: That looks like it will. I'll have to try it out sometime. Thanks!